# How to set month and day from one table to new stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

```
declare
    @pm_WeekEndDate DATETIME,
    @lp_Day VARCHAR(10),
    @intDate DATETIME

set @pm_WeekEndDate = MONTH(@pm_WeekEndDate)
set @lp_Day = day(@pm_WeekEndDate)
set @intDate = (@pm_WeekEndDate & @lp_Day)
```

This code should take month january then = 1 because other table has all in numbers like month 1 to 12 and day 1 to 7.

But I am getting this error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PRO, Line60
>   The data types datetime and varchar are incompatible in the '&' operator.

Comment: This is not even close to what you think is going on here. When you set a datetime variable to MONTH(DateValue) it will be a date set in january of 1900. Same thing using DAY. Perhaps if you can explain what you are really trying to do here we can help. Also mysql <> sqlserver...you should only tag the DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: The error message is SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.  I will also note that the question doesn't make sense to me.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a guess by on extremely vague details and having this kind of poor table design in the past. Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
declare @pm_WeekEndDate DATETIME = getdate()

select @pm_WeekEndDate

declare @DateVal char(4)

select @DateVal = right('00' + convert(varchar(2), MONTH(@pm_WeekEndDate)), 2) + right('00' + convert(varchar(2), DAY(@pm_WeekEndDate)), 2)

select @DateVal
```

Please notice that you can't have the result be a date because it doesn't make sense. I am guessing that your table has dates stored as either strings or ints??

Comment: If this works for your situation you should consider marking this as the answer.